# How to send Avro schema to GCP BigQuery using Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-bigquery, avro

I'm trying to send avro schema to GCP BigQuery using Java 11 and Spring 2. I've researched a lot of information, but I didn't find an example how to send avro file schema in format like:

```
{"namespace": "example.gcp",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Client",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "id", "type": "long"},
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "phone", "type": ["string", "null"]},
    {"name": "address", "type": ["string", "null"]}
  ]
}
```

I can send as binary file in format `.avro` using this snippet of code:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFileAvro")
public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("tableName") String tableName)
        throws IOException {

    ListenableFuture<Job> loadJob = this.bigQueryTemplate.writeDataToTable(
            tableName, file.getInputStream(), FormatOptions.avro());

    return getResponse(loadJob, tableName);
}
```

and in format `.csv` file using code like this:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFileCSV")
public ModelAndView handleFileUploadCSV(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("tableName") String tableName)
        throws IOException {

    ListenableFuture<Job> loadJob = this.bigQueryTemplate.writeDataToTable(
            tableName, file.getInputStream(), FormatOptions.csv());

    return getResponse(loadJob, tableName);
}
```

but when I'm trying to send schema file not binary file in format `.avro`, I'm getting the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.cloud.gcp.bigquery.core.BigQueryException: Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid data file. Magic does not match: gs://bigquery-prod-upload-us/prod-scotty-fa6aadb4-b3d6-40db-a39f-2025f1a99019
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:119)
    at org.springframework.cloud.springbootbigqueryapp.controller.WebController.getResponse(WebController.java:107)
    at org.springframework.cloud.springbootbigqueryapp.controller.WebController.handleFileUpload(WebController.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.gcp.bigquery.core.BigQueryException: Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid data file. Magic does not match: gs://bigquery-prod-upload-us/prod-scotty-fa6aadb4-b3d6-40db-a39f-2025f1a99019
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.bigquery.core.BigQueryTemplate.lambda$createJobFuture$0(BigQueryTemplate.java:170)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
```

Please, can someone enlighten me how to send avro schema file to GCP BigQuery?

P.S. As I understand correctly from [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftsfpPDwwD4), I can do that programmatically somehow.

Comment: A Schema file is JSON, not Avro, so trying to write it as Avro (or with format options of CSV) doesn't make sense... BigQuery would already know the schema from the binary Avro data written to it (which subsequent requests would deny based on the schema it knows, thus, the error)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added format `csv` as example which is worked properly for me, when I'm sending csv file to GCP BigQuery. So, as I understand you, I can send only as JSON instead of avro?

Comment: That might work, but I'm not sure the use case because you'd ideally only have a handful of schemas, and BigQuery is a analytics tool for large datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't have the concept of a schema registry itself, so you're likely going to want to use schema to either create a table, or load data into bigquery.

In the table creation case, you'd want to convert the avro schema to a bigquery schema.  BigQuery doesn't use avro schema representations directly.  Here's an example in java of creating tables with explicit schema: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-table#bigquery_create_table-java

In the load case, there's no need to transmit the schema independently of the data.  The Avro OCF structure typically includes the schema as part of the header, plus a set of data blocks.  Just specify the URI for the avro files: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-gcs-avro#bigquery_load_table_gcs_avro-java